# Making a D3 widget scrollable

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, scroll

I'm sticking a D3 tree widget into my web app. It grows children and appends them to the tree. However, when the tree gets to be too big, it starts to go off the page. That's fine since I don't want to the individual tree nodes to get too small, but it would be nice if I could add a scroll bar. However, I've tried doing it the normal way, `overflow: auto`, but it doesn't work. Maybe it's something to do with the D3 svg stuff.

Here's the code for a tree with 2 nodes:

```
<div id="Graph">
  <svg width="100%" height="10%" id="SVG" overflow="auto" display="block">
    <g transform="translate(40,0)">
      <path class="link" d="M0,20C213.75,20 213.75,20 427.5,20"></path>
      <g class="node" transform="translate(427.5,20)">
        <circle r="4.5" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></circle>
        <text x="10" dy=".35em" text-anchor="start" style="fill-opacity: 1;">1</text>
      </g>
      <g class="node" transform="translate(0,20)">
        <circle r="4.5" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></circle>
        <text x="-10" dy=".35em" text-anchor="end" style="fill-opacity: 1;">0</text>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Once it gets to be more than around 10 or 11 nodes, it goes off the screen. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the width of the svg element > 100%. That will overflow the div and the div will be scrollable. You might also need to set the overflow style to scroll on the `<div>`